# Biber not run automatically with `-shell-escape`?

Tags: biber, shell-escape

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that `biber` can be run automatically by the `biblatex` package when `-shell-escape` is allowed.

Do I remember it wrong? As much as I try, biblatex only tells me to run `biber` by hand.

**EDIT** using TexLive2010 (updated about one month ago).

**EDIT2** (MWE): I run this code with `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`; I expected `biber` to be run automatically by `biblatex` using `\write18`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{aa.bib}
    @book{FooBar2000, author={Foo Bar}, title={Some Title}, publisher={Springer}, year={2000}};
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{aa.bib}

\begin{document}
    According to \cite{FooBar2000} \dots
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide with a MWE? And tell us exactly what is wrong? What distribution are you using, what are the commands that you are invoking to compile etc...

Comment: @Martigan: Really? This is one of those rare occasions where an MWE makes no sense.

Comment: @Mark: A minimal example makes sense. I could copy and paste and so try in a easy way if the automatic call works for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I stand by my comment. I can't see how an MWE would expedite anything in this case, since the answer will either be from someone who is reading or has read the manual, is a google wizard, or who already knows how to do it. MWEs are *usually* a good thing to put into a question, but not at the cost of being concise.

Comment: It is not a MWE per se that we need, but still a Minimum Configuration Description, if you prefer...

Comment: @Martigan: You're going to have to elaborate on that, or put it into the question as an edit.

Comment: @Martigan: I also think MWE makes it only less clear. The question is about whether is biblatex **supposed** to run biber automatically by design in the first place; if so, only then a MWE makes sense.

Comment: I am fairly sure that biblatex won't do this automatically. You might want to look at latexmk which will automate an entire workflow involving *latex+biblatex+biber in a much more flexible way than a `\write18` call will

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no provision for running `biber` automatically, nor has there ever been. Neither `biblatex` nor `biber` mention such an option in their documentation, so I think you must have been mistaken.

If you use `latexmk` it will automatically run `biber` as needed.

Comment: It might do it, but not at the time of `\printbibliography`, as the `.aux` file must be closed; so this wouldn't spare a LaTeX run.